How to properly fit a CanvasTexture on a mesh in Three.js?
I'm working on a project that involves applying a 2D canvas texture onto a mesh of a 3D model (specifically, projecting a canvas that imitates Windows 95 onto the screen of a computer model). My goal is to make this texture interactive, so I can navigate the model's screen as if I were using Windows 95.
I've followed these steps so far:

Imported the model into Blender to separate the specific mesh (the screen) from the rest of the model.
Exported the model as a .glb file and loaded it into my JavaScript file.
Located the mesh I want (named "pc_screen") and applied the texture.

Everything works well up to this point—I can see my canvas displayed on the screen of the model.
However, I'm struggling with fitting the texture properly onto the screen mesh. Using offset and repeat for alignment has been very challenging to fine-tune manually, and I feel there might be a better way to handle this.
Code
Here's the code I'm working with:
Loading the texture with dimensions:
it seem like i don't have to add 'dimensions' on params but i tried...
const Wintexture = createWindows95Texture(84.9448561668396, 63.90901794154992);

Applying the texture to the mesh:
computerModel.traverse((child) => {
    if (child.isMesh && child.name === "pc_screen") {
        const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: Wintexture });
        child.material = material;
    }
});

Trying to adjust the texture with offset and repeat:

Wintexture.repeat.set(1, 1);
Wintexture.offset.set(1, 1);
Wintexture.needsUpdate = true;


Creating the canvas texture:
here is how i started to create my canvas texture:
export default function createWindows95Texture(width, height) {
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    
    // Drawing content on the canvas...

and how it finish :
 return new THREE.CanvasTexture(canvas);
}

What I've Tried

I tried manually adjusting offset and repeat values, but it's tough to get it right. I’m looking for a more accurate or automated way to fit the canvas texture perfectly onto the screen mesh.
Is there a recommended approach to aligning textures on specific meshes in Three.js? Or should I consider some kind of mathematical calculation to automate the fitting process?
Any guidance would be appreciated!
